# get list of selected checkbox value in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to get list of selected checkbox values. How can I do that?I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC 5 app. This app has a basic form. 
[image]

My view code

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Field  Name</th>
                @foreach (var field in Model.Actions)
                {
                    <th>@field.Name</th>
                }
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            @foreach (var permission in Model.PermissionUserField)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td> @permission.Field.Name</td>
                    @foreach (var peruserAction in permission.PermissionUserFieldActions)
                    {
                        <td>
                            @if (peruserAction.Active)
                            {
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x=> x.PermissionUserFieldForUser)

                                <input type="checkbox" checked name="field_@(permission.FieldId)_[@peruserAction.Id]" />
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <input type="checkbox" name="field_@(permission.FieldId)_[@peruserAction.Id]" />
                            }
                        </td>
                    }

                </tr>
            }

        </tbody>
    </table>

    <br />

    <input type="submit" value="Save" />

}
```

The model for my form looks like the following:

```
 public class NewViewModel
    {
        public List<PermissionUserField> PermissionUserField{ get; set; }
        public List<PermissionUserField> PermissionUserFieldForUser { get; set; }
        public List<Action> Actions { get; set; }
        public List<Field> Field { get; set; }

    }

 public partial class Action
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }

    public partial class PermissionUserField
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }
        public int FieldId { get; set; }
        public Field Field { get; set; }    
        public List<PermissionUserFieldAction> PermissionUserFieldActions { get; set; }
    }
    public partial class PermissionUserFieldAction
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ActionId { get; set; }
        public Action Action { get; set; }
        public int PermissionUserFieldId { get; set; }
        public PermissionUserField PermissionUserField { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; } = false;
    }
```

My controller code:

Comment: Um... you appear to have left your controller code out?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using Html.CheckBoxFor ?

Comment: You not giving your checkboxes a `value`. But you cannot use a `foreach` loop to generate form controls for a collection - refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943) nor can you bind a hidden input to a complex object.

Comment: Create an actionMethod within your controller, which accepts FormCollection or Your ViewModel and when you will press submit, the method will be called, you'll automatically get values of those checkboxes.

Comment: Use a `for` loop and `@Html.CheckboxFor()` to bind to your `bool` property - `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.PermissionUserField[i].PermissionUserFieldActions[j].IsActive)`

Answer (score 0):

The names of the checkbox should be the same to be binded in a list.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15966974)

Comment: The question was : `I want to get list of selected checkbox values` and an example where he's binding different name to its checkbox list. So it's not a remarks or critics, just the answer. I can write an example where the name are same if this is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with HttpPost, also you can do this with JQuery

```
var checkedArray=
 $('input:checkbox').each(function () {//iterate all checboxes in page
        var data={ "IsChecked":   this.checked ,"Name":this.attr('name')}
      checkedArray.push();

        });
```

and then send checkedArray to controller via ajax